# gnuplot a lot of repeated entries in svg

Tags: svg, gnuplot

I generate quite a lot of points with uniform scale and color:

```
set term svg size 600 600
set output "random_samples.svg"

set size square
set xrange [-0.05:1.05]
set yrange [-0.05:1.05]

plot "sorted_samples.data" using 1:2 with linespoints pt 7 pointsize 0.2 linewidth 0.3 linecolor "black" notitle
```

When number of samples grows my SVG files start to become very heavy. I had a look inside of the SVG file and it seems that there are many entries that are repeated:

```
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(451.7,96.7) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(462.0,92.1) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(284.3,73.6) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(242.5,278.1) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(405.9,285.2) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(166.8,55.8) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(168.4,61.4) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(166.8,119.7) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(541.0,64.0) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
    <use xlink:href='#gpPt6' transform='translate(421.2,100.2) scale(0.90)' color='rgb(148,   0, 211)'/>
```

By using text editor I removed `scale` and `color`. By doing this I can reduce file size from 2.3MB to 1.3MB. That is a significant difference.

Is there a way to output more optimised SVGs from gnuplot?

P.S. I am looking for some more automated solution rather than manually going file by file.

Comment: It seems like `svgo`(https://github.com/svg/svgo) does really good job.